# Failed to install react-native-web@~0.18.7, react-dom with error: npm exited with non-zero code: 1 npm exited with non-zero code: 1

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to start a expo project on web but it throws this error, Can anyone help me please?

Press a │ open Android
› Press w │ open web

› Press r │ reload app
› Press m │ toggle menu

› Press ? │ show all commands

Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
Started Metro Bundler
√ It looks like you're trying to use web support but don't have the required dependencies installed. Would you like to install
react-native-web, react-dom? ... yes

× Failed to install react-native-web@~0.18.7, react-dom with error: npm exited with non-zero code: 1
npm exited with non-zero code: 1
?
› Stopped server
C:\Users\Human\News-Application>expo start

This command is being executed with the global Expo CLI. Learn more: https://blog.expo.dev/the-new-expo-cli-f4250d8e3421
To use the local CLI instead (recommended in SDK 46 and higher), run:
› npx expo start

Starting project at C:\Users\Human\News-Application
"react-native-web" is added as a dependency in your project's package.json but it doesn't seem to be installed. Please run "yarn" or "npm install" to fix this issue.

C:\Users\Human\News-Application>npm install react-native-web
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: news-application@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^17.0.2 || ^18.0.0" from react-native-web@0.18.12
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-web
npm ERR!     react-native-web@"~0.18.7" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   peer react-dom@"^17.0.2 || ^18.0.0" from react-native-web@0.18.12
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-web
npm ERR!     react-native-web@"~0.18.7" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Human\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-02-10T03_04_04_748Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Human\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-02-10T03_04_04_748Z-debug-0.log

I tried insalling react-native-web with npm install and I was expecting smooth installation but it says Failed to install react-native-web@～0.18.7 with error: npm exited with non-zero code: 1

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by doing a force install as the console messages were suggesting and then using expo doctor (again as the console messages were suggestion) to fix the dependency issue.

`npm install react-native-web, react-dom --force`

and once the installation is done, do:

`expo doctor --fix-dependencies`

My app runs successfully afterwards.